# Фиксированная ширина сайта

Tags: html, css

Прописал в ...

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width = 960, initial-scale=1">
```

Но не появляется ползунок, когда ширина меньше 960px. Как сделать фиксированную ширину сайта, меньше которой блоки (у меня на них display flex justify-content center) перестанут ползти и просто появится скролл?

Comment: `width=device-width`, а в CSS для body прописать `width: 960px`

Comment: используйте `min-width: 960px;` для общего блока flex

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство overflow - управляет отображением содержания блочного элемента, если оно целиком не помещается и выходит за область заданных размеров.

В вашем конкретном случае вам понадобится следующее свойство:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Для того чтобы задать скрулл по конкретной оси (x или y) можно использовать следующие команды:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```